# WKWebView - didFinishNavigation or decidePolicyForNavigationResponse not being called on goBack action

Tags: wkwebview

I am not sure whether its a usual behavior or not, but, on `[WKWebView goBack]` navigates to previous page from the Back-Forward list. but, in my case on very first back action, it does not calls `didFinishNavigation` delegate method.

So, if it's usual behavior then how to detects that page loading is completed after back the action.

Answer (score 1):

I even see this on the simulator. Navigate to google.com, click privacy, then `goBack` and while the page loads normally, navigation reports a failure with error:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.google.com/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.google.com/, _WKRecoveryAttempterErrorKey=<WKReloadFrameErrorRecoveryAttempter: 0x600003904e40>}
```

What you need to do is capture this with the `didFailNavigation:` delegate method and handle it gracefully (if you see a consistent error like the above you can even treat it exactly the same as success).

Comment: Same issue, it's weird, it went to didFailNavigation: delegate when invoke goBack().
Any solution here?

Comment: @Ethan.Li what iOS are you on? I don't see it happening anymore (on iOS 17). I had used that workaround of treating didFailNavigation as success for a while...

Comment: iOS 17.0, simulator

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing this on a specific iOS version? Im seeing this too, only and error is being thrown and the page just stops loading, hence didFinish... not being called.

I've only started seeing this since 13.4 (or 13.4.1)

**--- EDIT ---**

I do have a workaround.

This appears to happen more often on slower networks and when the user interacts before a page is fully loaded. Normally if a user taps back before the page they visited finished loading then a "Cancelled" error is thrown.

What seems to be happening now is, if the page they are returning to never finished loading at the point they left, then the error is thrown again, but this time referencing the page they are returning to. and more importantly the web view is no longer loading at this point.

what we have done is monitor this and check to see if the page is not loading, and if it isn't, reload it. This seems to work and while not ideal, its buying us some time to investigate a proper fix.

In addition, I put a retry limit on this and we show an error with a reload button after the third attempt, though in practice we've never seen it go beyond the first reload attempt.

The fact that the error is thrown almost instantaneously means the reload adds no perceivable delay for the user.

Comment: For me, this is happening in 13.5